# get form data using model foreignkey relation in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am quite new to Django an I am working on an online Exam application where user would be having questions and their options to select and a submit button so that once submitted it will go to next question.
What the problem is I am not able to get options for a particular question.
My question is:

- How to start from the 1st question
- Get all options/choices for a question

Here are my code snippet:
MODEL:

```
class QuestionTbl(models.Model):
    ques_id=models.IntegerField()
    Text=models.TextField(max_length=200)
    marks=models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Text

class AnswerTbl(models.Model):
    ques=models.ForeignKey(QuestionTbl)
    Option=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    iscorrect=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' %(self.Option)
```

view:

```
def loadQuestions(request):
   if request.method=='POST':
       form=AnswerForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
   else:
       form=AnswerForm()
   return render(request,"Pages/questions.html",{"form":form})
```

I tried using `val=form.MultiplechoiceField(queryset=AnswerTbl.objects.get(id=anyquesid))`.But again I am not sure how to pass every time the **id** into the query OR autoincrement it.

In the above code,**questions.htm**l is in Page folder.

Comment: could you post your code for the `AnswerForm`?

Comment: Can you also show your urls.py

Comment: @Remi!! Pls find the Answerform

    <form method="POST" action="/ExamApp/question/">
 {%csrf_token%}
   {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit" />
 </form>>

Comment: @dkarchmer!! pls see the url:

urlpatterns=[
            
            url(r'^question/', views.loadQuestions,name='question'),
            
            ]